# Remove shadow effect when window is maximised in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I had an window with styles

```
Background="Transparent", AllowsTransparency="True", WindowStyle="None",  ResizeMode="NoResize".
```

I had placed custom min, max, close buttons and implemented functionality.And as i want the window to resize the window on all the sides. i implemented it with `HwndSource` which works fine. Now my concern is i want shadow effect for the window.so i placed the border with shadow effect like this.

```
<Border CornerRadius="5" Margin="10">

    <Border.BitmapEffect>
        <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="10" Opacity=".5" Softness="9" />
    </Border.BitmapEffect>

    <Grid> **Content over here**</Grid>
</Border>
```

window gets the shadow effect. but when i maximise the window. it does not fit to the screen as i had added border. i need to remove the shadow effect when window is maximized so that it fit to the screen. and the shadow effect should appear when window is in not in maximized state. how to get this or is there any another method to get this.. please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be possible to add/remove the shadow effect dynamically in the code by creating style for your Border. You can create a style for your border something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="borderstyle" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowBitmapEffect ShadowDepth="10">   </DropShadowBitmapEffect>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

And then set it dynamically in the code

borderelement.Style =(Style)Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["borderstyle"];

and remove it by using the following code

borderelement.Style = null

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to determine if Window is maximized and then in the trigger setter, remove the effect. Just overload template for the Window and inside ControlTemplate triggers add a trigger

```
 <Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
        <Border x:Name="brd">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="20" Color="Black"/>
            </Border.Effect>
            <Grid Width="200" Height="200" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1" Background="Red"/>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="brd" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

</Window.Template>
```